# How to specify virtual path for image in ASP.Net MVC razor helper

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my razor style helper class (located in the App_Code folder, I've got this line of code:

```
<img src="../../Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading"/>
```

This works fine in Cassini, but when I deploy the app to IIS (virtual directory), IIS can't find the path. The virtual path is being ignored.
This also doesn't work:

```
<img src="@Href("~/Content/images/ajax_activity.gif")" alt="loading" />
```

Comment: `This also doesn't work` ... Why not? Please show us the generated HTML.

Comment: Hi SLaks. As this is an ajax call within a jQuery dialog box, there is no way (at least I don't know any) to see the generated source, but watching it in Firebug, I get the following error message: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/Content/images/ajax_activity.gif".  I have set up the virtual directory to be Merkur, so the real path should be http://localhost/Merkur/Content/images/ajax_activity.gif.

Comment: And another thing. Both samples above work fine when called from within a view. The problem seems to be related to having the helpers located in the App_Code directory (need them to be there because I call them from multiple views).

Comment: Great, it's there and it is returning the following: <img src="../../Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, solved it, though I'm not really sure why it's working. After trying all the following combinations without success:

```
<img src="../Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading"/>
<img src="/Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading"/>
<img src="~/Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading"/>
<img src="Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading"/>
```

the following finally worked as expected

```
<img src="./Content/images/ajax_activity.gif" alt="loading"/>
```

It returned the image path correctly with the virtual directory set. Anyone able to explain this?

Comment: Late reply, but `./Stuff/foo.bar` will look in the base directory of the application for `Stuff/foo.bar`. `~/Stuff/foo.bar` corresponds to a virtual path which you presumably did not configure. `../Stuff/foo.bar` is a relative path that looks in the parent directory for `Stuff/foo.bar`. `Stuff/foo.bar` looks in the current directory, and `/Stuff/foo.bar`.. well, I can't explain that one. I would have expected that one to also look in the base directory. Stumbled across this while trying to fix similar solution. Point being these can all be different, which is why it might not work.

Comment: Wouldn't Stuff/foo.bar be the "Stuff subdirectory" in the current directory?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant `Stuff/foo.bar` would look in the current directory for `Stuff/foo.bar`

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/ajax_activity.gif")" alt="loading" />
```

Comment: This results in the following compiler error: CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

Comment: This worked for me. Probably more applicable to a broader range of environments.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `@Url.Content` method to convert virtual relative path to absolute application path like this:

```
<img src=@Url.Content("~/images/picture.png") alt="picture description">
```

It'll be converted in this HTML code forwarded to client:

```
<img src="/appname/images/picture.png" alt="picture description">
```

UPDATE:
In other hand you could convert image to base64 and it will be displayed correctly too:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...SuQmCC" alt="picture description">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy in a virtual directory in IIS, the app root may be different from what you had in your dev environment.

If your app url si something like

```
http://localhost/MyWebApp/
```

ASP.NET will consider the root is "localhost", when it should be "MyWebApp".

To solve this, you have to convert the virtual directory to an application : in IIS Manager, find your directory, right clic on it, and then "Convert to application".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but the information I needed was here.

For me the missing part was "When Published".  So for any future developers looking for how to work with web config transformations, the process I follow is:

1. Add a transformation file for each project configuration (i.e. deployment)
2. Add the environment specific elements (don't forget the xdt attributes)
3. Modify the Web.config for your local development.

When the project is published, the transformation will occur.